# How to display two results within one query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query below that is able to calculate the total weighting of each team based on the 11 players it choose from:

```
SELECT TeamID, SUM(PlayerWeighting) as TeamWeight
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM(
            SELECT pl.*,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pl.TeamID, pl.Position ORDER BY NEWID()) AS Rnk
            FROM(
                SELECT DISTINCT p.PlayerID, p.Position, p.PlayerWeighting, p.FirstName, p.Surname, t.TeamID, t.TeamAbbreviation, f.WeekNumber
                FROM dbo.Fixture f
                INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON f.LeagueID = l.LeagueID
                INNER JOIN dbo.Team t ON l.LeagueID = t.LeagueID
                INNER JOIN dbo.Player p ON t.TeamID = p.TeamID
                WHERE f.WeekNumber = 1) 
                pl) po
        WHERE (po.position = 'GK' and po.rnk = 1) OR 
              (po.position = 'DF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
              (po.position = 'MF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
              (po.position = 'FW' and po.rnk <= 2) ) as T
    GROUP BY T.TeamID
```

The second SELECT statement within the above query actually outputs the list of players per team (this was tested before I placed in the first SELECT statement to calculate the total).

What I want to do is somehow display two results. One results showing the team weighting and another results showing the players involved in each team weighting. How do I get the above query to show both results in one execution?

Thank you

UPDATE:

Below is what the query looks like if I execute the whole code:

[image]

Below is the player weighting results when I comment out the first SELECT statement in the query:

[image]

I just want both tables to appear separately when they are executed. Obviously I can't just copy the query and paste it below and remove the first select statement because the players in the second query could be different to the team weighting generated in the first query if that makes sense

Comment: Can you provide some sample results?

Comment: @qxg I have provided an update in the question to show the results

Comment: How they can be different? Because data is changing frequently? If yes then you can save the results of the inner query in a temporary / memory table then use that (temporary table) for further displaying 2 result sets.

Comment: @sallushan Can you show me an example on you will implement this using your method of temp/memory table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use `SUM() OVER()` without the outer query :

```
    SELECT po.*,
           SUM(po.playerWeighting) OVER(PARTITION BY po.teamID) as teamWeight
    FROM(
        SELECT pl.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pl.TeamID, pl.Position ORDER BY NEWID()) AS Rnk
        FROM(
            SELECT DISTINCT p.PlayerID, p.Position, p.PlayerWeighting, p.FirstName, p.Surname, t.TeamID, t.TeamAbbreviation, f.WeekNumber
            FROM dbo.Fixture f
            INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON f.LeagueID = l.LeagueID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Team t ON l.LeagueID = t.LeagueID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Player p ON t.TeamID = p.TeamID
            WHERE f.WeekNumber = 1) 
            pl) po
    WHERE (po.position = 'GK' and po.rnk = 1) OR 
          (po.position = 'DF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
          (po.position = 'MF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
          (po.position = 'FW' and po.rnk <= 2)
```

`SUM() OVER()` is an analytic function mostly used for cumulative sum. When no `ORDER BY` mentioned after the `PARTITION BY` , this will simply return the total sum for each group mentioned in the `PARTITION BY` part.

Answer (score 0):

While @sagi's answer is good, you have 1 result set with all the things you need. But still if you insist for 2 results you can use a table variable, for example like this,

```
DECLARE @testTable table(column1 int, column2 varchar(100));

INSERT INTO @testTable(column1, column2)
    SELECT  1, 'abc';           -- <- you can put your query here


-- first result set
SELECT  *
FROM    @testTable;         

-- second result set
SELECT  COUNT(1) AS TotalRows
FROM    @testTable;
```